# Reactjs - calling a component and passing a string variable

Tags: reactjs, calling-convention, react-component

I have a React component called Logging which accepts a string variable "newLogEntry" and updates a textarea which contains all the log messages.

I want to be able to call this component from anywhere in the code (index.js, App.jsx etc).

I want a text string returned: "log updated"

I cannot find a way to call the Logging component from within a function.  All the examples I have seen so far assume the components initiate the process, but for my application the process must be initiated in the index.js or App.jsx code.

Some assistance would be geatly appreciated.

This is the Logging component code:

```
   import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

var userMessage = "New log message added";

function UpdateLog(props) {
  const newLogEntry = "props.logmessage";
  var logsAll = "ConsoleLog: " + document.getElementById('Logs').innerHTML;
  logsAll = newLogEntry  + "|" + logsAll;


  ReactDOM.render(
  (logsAll),
  document.getElementById("Logs")
  )
}


export default(userMessage);
```

Comment: Had a quick look and not sure if this's the reason, but you exported userMessage instead of UpdateLog (?

Answer (score 0):

On quick look at the code and your description, it looks like your not able to access the component from anywhere in your code. This is because your export is not exporting the function to render. Modify that to 
'''
export default updateLog
'''

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out.  However that  requires the importing code to do something with the function when it receives it - and I want to update the log in the Logging component itself to avoid creating lots of code every time I want to update the log.

That means I am not expecting to export anything, even though I have to create a dummy export to satisfy the compiler.

I tried another approach, generating a replacement <div> for the log but I could not figure out how to make that work either. :-(